# translations and equidecomposability

Tags: geometry

sorry if the question has already been discussed somewhere else, I did not found it if such the case.

In the main proof of the well-known equidecomposability result concerning two polygons of same area, most of the time only translations are involved, except in the first step, when a rotation naturally appears to transform the triangle into a parallelogram. Now, if rotations are forbidden and if all pieces have to be measurable, does the result still hold? (the result with non measurable pieces is more difficult to understand and I don't really see what happens here, but this is true).

Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Croft, Falconer, & Guy's ["Unsolved Problems in Geometry"](https://books.google.com/books?id=rdDTBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA104) (1991) mentions results by Laczkovich that affirm translation-only equidecomposability of modestly-restricted sets w/equal measure, but using (presumably) non-measurable components. (A web search turned up [an "expository piece" (PDF)](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Ramsey.pdf) on the results.) I might have expected the book to mention a measurable, translation-only result for polygons, if such a result existed. Then again, that was a few years ago.

Comment: thanks for the reference... well, I still don't understand whether it solves or not the problem!

Comment: I'm quite certain that what I referenced doesn't *solve* your problem; rather, it seems to establish somewhat authoritatively that the problem was *unsolved* as of 1991 or so. This compares to rotation-and-translation equidecomposability of polygons, which was [settled independently by Wallace, Bolyai, and Gerwien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallace–Bolyai–Gerwien_theorem) in the early 1800s. (The Wikipedia entry's lack of information on a translation-only result may indicate that the problem remains open.) Anyway, I thought the additional context would be helpful to readers.